# Update with inner join in Oracle not working

Tags: oracle, ms-access, sql-update

Converting query from Access to Oracle is not working

**Access**

```
UPDATE 
     Table1 
INNER JOIN      
     Table2
ON  (Table1.ID = Table2.ID) AND (Table1.AREA = Table2.AREA) 
SET Table2.LAT = Table1.LAT, Table2.LON = Table1.LON;
```

**Oracle**

```
UPDATE 
    Table1 
SET
    Table2.LAT= (SELECT Table1.LAT FROM Table1  WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID  AND Table1.AREA = Table2.AREA );
```

Getting this error in Oracle

Error report -

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "Table2"."LAT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Looking for correct equivalent in Oracle.

Comment: Your equivalent is already correct. But you should update column Table2.LAT in Table2, not in Table1. That's why you're getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a merge statement, something like:

```
merge into table2 tgt
  using table1 src
    on (tgt.id = src.id and tgt.area = src.area)
when matched then
  update set tgt.lat = src.lat,
             tgt.lon = src.lon;
```

which should be more performant than the corresponding update statement:

```
UPDATE table2
SET    (table2.lat, table2.lon) = (SELECT table1.lat,
                                          table1.lon
                                   FROM   table1
                                   WHERE  table1.id = table2.id
                                   AND    table1.area = table2.area)
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT NULL
               FROM   table1
               WHERE  table1.id = table2.id
               AND    table1.area = table2.area);
```

as the update needs to repeat the subquery twice to ensure it only updates the correct rows, whereas the merge does a join on the two tables.

Comment: It worked !, fixed slight syntax issue () required after ON

Comment: @addcolor of course! \*slaps forehead\* I’ve updated my answer too 